# App failing to push to heroku because of gem bundler (Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts (/home/group_home/.ssh/known_hosts))

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, bundler, spree, gemfile

I had encountered this error when attempting to push a spree sandbox cart to test an extension I was going to use.

My Gemfile

```
gem 'spree_flexi_variants', :git=>'git@github.com:jsqu99/spree_flexi_variants.git', :branch => 'pre-deface-stable'
```

The output of heroku push:

```
julio@ubuntu:~/rails/sandboxcart $ git push heroku master
Counting objects: 502, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (475/475), done.
Writing objects: 100% (502/502), 2.63 MiB | 458 KiB/s, done.
Total 502 (delta 44), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Heroku receiving push
-----> Ruby/Rails app detected
-----> Detected Rails is not set to serve static_assets
       Installing rails3_serve_static_assets... done
-----> Configure Rails 3 to disable x-sendfile
       Installing rails3_disable_x_sendfile... done
-----> Configure Rails to log to stdout
       Installing rails_log_stdout... done
-----> Gemfile detected, running Bundler version 1.0.7
       Unresolved dependencies detected; Installing...
       Using --without development:test
       Fetching source index for http://rubygems.org/
       Fetching git@github.com:jsqu99/spree_flexi_variants.git
       Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts (/home/group_home/.ssh/known_hosts).
       Permission denied (publickey).
       fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
       An error has occurred in git when running `git clone "git@github.com:jsqu99/spree_flexi_variants.git" "/disk1/tmp/build_1s7xejrz2f9xk/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/cache/bundler/git/spree_flexi_variants-fc5500c20fdd64421924c0c5673538c7c6822540" --bare --no-hardlinks`. Cannot complete bundling.
       FAILED: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to install gems via Bundler
```

The app runs and uses the gem properly but upon trying to deploy that error occurs. I am still in the process of trouble shooting but any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 9):

Do the following change:

```
gem 'spree_flexi_variants', :git=>'git@github.com:jsqu99/spree_flexi_variants.git', :branch => 'pre-deface-stable'
```

TO

```
gem 'spree_flexi_variants', :git=>"git://github.com/jsqu99/spree_flexi_variants.git", :branch => 'pre-deface-stable'
```

That should do it, and it has nothing to do with your heroku keys.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a problem with your SSH keys.

The [Heroku Site](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/keys) has instructions on how to manage SSH keys.

Try `heroku keys` and make sure that you have configured that properly.

Comment: The error has to do with the keys on the github site not on the heroku site, he has the problem when accessing github not heroku.

Comment: Skimmed it a little too shallow.  Oops.